# bash to copy file 3 times and rename each using lines in another file

Tags: bash

In the `bash` below I am trying to copy the single text file in `/home/cmccabe/QC/test/metrics.txt` 3 times. Each one of the 3 text files is then renamed using lines 3-5 (always the same), from `/home/cmccabe/QC/analysis.txt`. However, I am getting an error and not sure how to fix it.  Thank you :).

**metrics.txt** (`tab-delimited`)

```
R_Index ISP Loading Pre-Enrichment  Total Reads Read Length Key Signal  Usable Sequence Enrichment  Polyclonal  Low Quality Test Fragment   Aligned Bases   Unaligned Bases Exception
1   89  .   78402052    201 77  61  98.6    29.2    10.4    79  98.8    1.2
```

**analysis.txt**

```
status: complete
id names: 
00-0000_Last-First
01-0101_LastN-FirstN
02-0202_La-Fi
```

**attempt**

```
LinesToSkip=2
((StartLine=$LinesToSkip+1))

files=($(cat /home/cmccabe/QC/test/metrics.txt ))

i=1

while read -r new_name
do
mv "${files[$i]}" "$new_name"
((i=$i+1))
done < <(sed -n "${StartLine},\$p" /home/cmccabe/QC/analysis.txt)

mv: cannot stat ‘ISP’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘Loading’: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘Pre-Enrichment’: No such file or directory
```

**desired output** (single column of data)

```
00-0000_Last-First_meterics.txt
01-0101_LastN-FirstN_metrics.txt
02-0202_La-Fi_metrics.txt
```

Comment: Hi Chris, one debugging method is to execute code in your head. Your issue is with the mv line. Translate your variables into their actual values, then ask yourself if the command makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You foundm, that you can get the new filenames with `sed`.
Now you can get mv commands using printf:

```
printf "mv metrix.txt %s\n" "$(sed '1,2 d' /home/cmccabe/QC/test/metrics.txt)"
```

Now get the output executed like the were regular commands with `<()`.

```
source <(printf "mv metrix.txt %s\n" "$(sed '1,2 d' /home/cmccabe/QC/test/metrics.txt)")
```

`source` can be replaced by a dot and would like to see double quotes in the filename (might have a space in it):

```
. <(printf 'mv metrix.txt "%s"\n' "$(sed '1,2 d' /home/cmccabe/QC/test/metrics.txt)")
```

Comment: Thank you both :)

Comment: I guess you already figured out, that you need a small adjustment for output files ending with `.txt`:  Just add it in the `printf 'mv metrix.txt "%s.txt"\n'`